# Not able to reset the values of form elements on change of select box in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I want to reset my form elements on `change` of select box value. The below is the example.

```
<sj:select
        id="uniqueId"
    requiredLabel="true" 

        name="choosenvalue"
        list="displayItems"
        listKey="key"
        listValue="value"
        headerKey="-1"
        headerValue="Choose displayed Items"

        onChangeTopics="change"
        href="%{findSelectedValues}"

    />  
<sj:spinner
    name="spinnner"
    id="spinner"
    min="1"
    step="1"
    value="1" />

<sj:datepicker  name="datepicker" requiredLabel="true" minDate="0" timepicker="true"  />
```

How to reset the values of `datepicker` and `spinner` from the values retrieved form the database on `change` the select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easily done via subscribing to the `changeTopic`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.subscribe("changeTopic", function(event,data) {
     $("#formID").resetForm();
 });
</script>
```

where the `formID` is an id of the form element. So, in `select` tag

```
onChangeTopics="changeTopic"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Probably I didn't put it correctly. I want to set the values of spinner and date field on change of select box the response comes back as JSON.

Comment: Thanks Roman. It works with Jquery ajax.  But just thinking if something is built into plugin so that we don't have to use Jquery directly

Comment: The plugin uses jQuery API to make Ajax requests from the tags managed by the plugin like anchor or div. It seems ugly to create such elements for triggering events on them only instead of use jQuery API directly.